# How to rotate SVG using d3.drag()?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have a simple rectangle appended as a SVG. I want to rotate it with a mouse mouse drag so I used the function `d3.drag()`. Here is what I have attempted in order to achieve this but it does not seem to work:

```
<div id = "svgcontainer"></div>
         <script language = "javascript">
            var width = 300;
            var height = 300;
            var origin = {
                x: 55,
                y: -40
            };
            var svg = d3.select("#svgcontainer")
               .append("svg")
               .attr("width", width)
               .attr("height", height);

            var group = svg.append("g");

            var rect = group.append("rect")
               .attr("x", 20)
               .attr("y", 20)
               .attr("width", 60)
               .attr("height", 30)
               .attr("fill", "green")

            group.call(d3.drag().on('drag', dragged));

            function dragged() {
                var r = {
                    x: d3.event.x,
                    y: d3.event.y
                };
                group.rotate([origin.x + r.x, origin.y + r.y]);
            };


         </script>
```

When I click on the rectangle and try to drag it to rotate, I am getting some error in the last line with `group.rotate(...)`. Can anyone please sort out the mistake in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group` is a d3 selection holding a `g`, it doesn't have a rotate method, but you can set the transform attribute for the selection with:

`group.attr("transform",rotate(θ,cx,cy));`

From the example, I'm unsure on how you want to rotate the block, I've set in in the example below to rotate around the center based on the movement of the drag along the x axis:

```js
var width = 300;
            var height = 300;
            var origin = {
                x: 50,
                y: 35
            };
            var svg = d3.select("#svgcontainer")
               .append("svg")
               .attr("width", width)
               .attr("height", height);

            var group = svg.append("g");

            var rect = group.append("rect")
               .attr("x", 20)
               .attr("y", 20)
               .attr("width", 60)
               .attr("height", 30)
               .attr("fill", "green")

            group.call(d3.drag().on('drag', dragged));

            function dragged() {
                var r = {
                    x: d3.event.x,
                    y: d3.event.y
                };
                group.attr("transform","rotate("+r.x+","+origin.x+","+origin.y+")" );
            };
```

```css
rect {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="svgcontainer"></div>
```